# Game ranking system: Finding the people who beat the people: How do I organize this csv data and append the file?

Tags: python, csv

I am creating a boardgame ranking system and I have a .CSV list of people who have defeated other people at boardgame night. Beating a person who has beaten another person counts as a win. I need to scrape this CSV file, find people who were defeated by the people defeated by the winners, then append that data and sort it.

I can open and create and grab data and write to the files, but when I try to write various versions of the the code, I can't seem to quite get the output right.

```
 import csv
 import collections

 #get the contents of the input.csv file
 WINLOSE = {}
 with open('input.csv') as f2:
     for line in f2:
         winners,losers = line.strip().split(',')
         WINLOSE[winners] = losers

 new_items = set()
 RESULTS = collections.namedtuple('RESULTS', ['winners', 'losers'])

 #Write to the output file.
 with open('output.csv', 'w') as f1:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(winners, losers)

 #pseudo code -- if any name in the winner cell appears in the 
 #loser cell,
 #copy all of the losers associated with that cell to the people 
 #who beat that
 #cell

     if cell.losers = any-cell.winners:
         append the losers associated with the winners cell
         for row in new_items:
             writer.writerow(row._asdict())
```

The input csv looks like this:

```
 Winners,Losers
 John,Amanda
 Mark,Eddy
 Amanda,Chad
 Becky,Michael
 Michael,Steve
 Eddy,Fred
 Michael, Stuart
 Edwardo, Patricia
 Michael, Buzz
 Mark, Charlie 
 Amanda, Brandon
 Brandon, Dirk
```

The output csv should look like this:

```
 Winners,Losers
 John,Amanda
 John,Chad
 John, Brandon
 John, Dirk
 Mark,Eddy
 Mark,Fred
 Mark, Charlie
 Amanda,Chad
 Becky,Michael
 Becky,Steve
 Michael,Steve
 Michael, Stuart
 Michael, Buzz
 Eddy,Fred
 Edwardo, Patricia
 Amanda, Brandon
 Brandon, Dirk
```

So for example, John beat Amanda and Amanda beat Chad, therefore we need tp add an entry that John beats Chad.

Comment: But if John did not play against Chad, why should you count it as a win? What if you do have a circular win/lose situation between three persons where each has won once and lost once?

Comment: @jbndlr: That's an excellent question. That problem is solved in our bracketing solution. The people who have both won and lost are in the loser bracket and won't be playing the pure winners again so you will never have a circular win/lose situation.

Comment: @Prune, thank you for that. Let me rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dict that maps each winner to a list of losers, iterate through the keys/winners of the dict, use a generator function that recursively yields the losers of a winner and output the resulting winner/loser pairs:

```
import csv

def find_losers(winner, results):
    for loser in results.get(winner, ()):
        yield loser
        for child in find_losers(loser, results):
            yield child

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f1, open('input.csv') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f2)
    writer = csv.writer(f1)
    writer.writerow(next(reader))
    results = {}
    for winner, loser in reader:
        results.setdefault(winner, []).append(loser)
    for winner in results:
        for loser in find_losers(winner, results):
            writer.writerow((winner, loser))
```

With your sample input, the output file will contain:

```
Winners,Losers
John,Amanda
John,Chad
John,Brandon
John,Dirk
Mark,Eddy
Mark,Fred
Mark,Charlie
Amanda,Chad
Amanda,Brandon
Amanda,Dirk
Becky,Michael
Becky,Steve
Becky,Stuart
Becky,Buzz
Michael,Steve
Michael,Stuart
Michael,Buzz
Eddy,Fred
Edwardo,Patricia
Brandon,Dirk
```

Comment: This works fine with the provided data set. When I use it against my actual data set, it seems to skip winning entries for people who have won more than once. So for example if my pairs are [Mark, John] [Mark, Ed] [Ed, Bill] [Steve, Ted] It will only list the for Mark's victory against ed, but not his victory against John. I've updated my provided data set to be a more accurate representation of the data. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: This is also true for people who have both lost and won multiple times.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it should work, however I'm getting this error: "  File "wins.py", line 6
    yield from find_losers(loser, results)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: The `yield from` statement was introduced in Python 3, so if you're using Python 2, you have to iterate over the generator and yield the output individually instead. I've updated my answer so that it works for Python 2 then.

Comment: You, sir, make the world a better place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in finding all possible start-end paths in a directed acyclic graph (DAG).

The problem with your posted code is that a dict must have unique keys; when you add `Mark: John` and then `Mark: Ted`, the first graph relation is deleted.  It's not a good structure for a graph.

I recommend the `igraph` module.  Build your graph, with each player represented as a node and each game represented as an edge from the winner to the loser.

Now it's a straightforward matter to find the nodes of undefeated players.  Follow each through the available paths, recording every possible pair of winner-loser transitivity.  Keep track of all the nodes you've visited on the path; each visited node will beat any node you later encounter.

Is that enough to get you moving?